# Compact Bilinear operators

Tags: real-analysis, bilinear-form, bilinear-operator

I was studying about Compact Bilinear Operators [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2013-141-10/S0002-9939-2013-11689-8/S0002-9939-2013-11689-8.pdf). I found the following definition:

**Definition** *Let $X,Y,Z$ be normed linear spaces. A Bilinear Operator $T:X\times Y\to Z$ is said to be compact if $T(B_X\times B_Y)$ is precompact in $Z$.*

If I consider $X,Y,Z$ to be reflexive Banach spaces, does the above definition reduces to the following:

**Query** *A Bilinear operator $T:X\times Y\to Z$ is compact if and only if for every pair of weakly convergent sequences $x_n\rightharpoonup x_0$ and $y_n\rightharpoonup y_0$, there holds $T(x_n,y_n)\to T(x_0,y_0)$.*

Also, I donot understand the meaning of precompact here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A set is precompact if its closure is compact

Comment: okay! you mean relatively compact@rubikscube09

Comment: Could you provide any light in context of my question?@rubikscube09

Comment: Sure - what exactly is your question?

Comment: My question is does the "definition" reduces to the query, if we assume $X,Y,Z$ to be reflexive@rubikscube09